# custom MultiValueRemove props does not work in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[image]

react-select allows for customizations of its different components, which is great but for some reason my custom `MultiValueRemove` (the x icon in a multi select) does not show. [Code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-39f3zs)

```
const MultiValueRemove = ({
    innerProps,
  }:MultiValueProps<NormalizedDropdown>) => (
    <components.MultiValueRemove {...innerProps}>
      <IconContainer>
        <Icon name="close" size={12} color="white" />
      </IconContainer>
    </components.MultiValueRemove>
  );
```

The X icon doesn't show up. This is how I'm using it...

```
<CreatableSelect
      options={options}
      components={{
        MultiValueRemove,
      }}
 />
```

Comment: Can you put your code on code sandbox?

Comment: @NearHuscarl Here is the code sandbox, I also posted it above in the problem description.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-39f3zs Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from the [docs](https://react-select.com/components#:%7E:text=Custom%20MultiValueRemove%20Example) has the props passed to the `component.MultiValueRemove`, not `innerProps`. Then `MultiValueRemove` uses the `props.innerProps` and pass it down to the child component, you can confirm it by passing the `innerProps` directly to the `div` element inside it:

```
const MultiValueRemove = (props: MultiValueRemoveProps<ColourOption>) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip content={'Customise your multi-value remove component!'} truncate>
      <components.MultiValueRemove {...props}>
        <EmojiIcon label="Emoji" primaryColor={colourOptions[2].color} />
      </components.MultiValueRemove>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

### [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4wpskc?file=src/App.js)